# How possible is it to publish a sequel with a different publisher than the original (successfully)?

Tags: publishing, fantasy, series, sequel, picture-books

How possible is it to publish a sequel with a different publisher than the original (successfully)?

Does the genre matter? Such as science fiction, fantasy, mysteries or picture books?

I would appreciate examples of when this has been done. The author I am asking for has published a picture book with sequels planned, as well as a fantasy, and there is no contract language dealing with sequels.

Comment: See also [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/42361/what-are-the-things-to-consider-when-writing-a-sequel-to-a-novel-from-another-au) question.

Comment: I vote to close this question as it is not about writing but about existing published works.

Comment: Questions about existing literary works are off topic for us, and should go to [Literature.se], though this one would be too broad for them. What is it that you're trying to find out? If what to wish to know is under what conditions you could publish a sequel with a different publisher than the original, that is a question we could answer. You should [edit] your question to reflect that, then. Take a look at our [tour] and [Ask] pages, they should explain what questions we can answer.

Comment: I voted against this edit because it's turned it into a completely different question.  While the new version is more on topic, it's not what the OP asked.  I feel that the OP needs to have a say in this, even if the question will be closed.

Comment: I voted to close as unclear until the OP returns to confirm what question they are asking. The edit is an on-topic question but a different one to what was asked. Other voters please do not reopen until OP responds.

Comment: @user37495 Welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn how things work around here. As you can see from the comments your initial question appeared to be off-topic. If you can clarify what you are actually asking we may be able to get this reopened. Thanks for participating and happy writing!

Comment: I am new here and willing to have my question edited to something acceptably on-topic. I (copyeditor/proofreader) am trying to help an author with the original question, as well as improve my own knowledge of the field to help other clients.

Comment: It seems to me that this is poerfectly clear, and not about existing works. This, as it strands is asking about how an authro can publish a second book in a series with a different publisher from the one that published the first. I am voting to reopen.

Comment: @Rasdashan, why did you roll back OP's edits? They made it into a perfectly on-topic question and now you've restored the off-topic version. I could understand if there were invalidated answers, but there aren't.

Comment: I voted to re-open because I know of some authors who have switched publishers mid-series (Pratchett in Germany) or loose series (Agatha Christie) , and I can imagine their editors/agents asking this question: Are we *trapped* with a publisher who puts soup ads in the text of my book (Pratchett) or who doesn't promote or undervalues  my works, or can I try for someplace new that may be a better fit?

Comment: I VTC yesterday but am satisfied with the OP's response to the edits and would retract my vote except that there have been enough "keep open" votes that there is nothing for me to retract anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Quite frankly, it all depends on your contract with your publisher.

If the publisher is already publishing your series (as a series) the publisher probably has a contract for that series.

If you wrote a novel and now want to write a series based on that novel, a series clause may not be in your contract but boiler plate contracts may cover derivative works.  Again check and, better still, have an attorney look at the contract.

Note that if you can start a series with another publisher based on your book, the original publisher will likely stop publishing your first book as revenge until and unless your series makes enough money to tempt the first publisher to cash in on the sale of the book.  Therefore, the series must be readable assuming no one read the first book.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the group!

Since you say you have already checked the contract and there is no clause relating to series, I'd say **it depends on the reason the series was dropped.** Just as an example, if the early books were selling really well but the publisher went out of business, an author could have luck selling to a new publisher with proven sales, especially if s/he can get the rights back to the earlier books.

However, this is rare and I don't know of any authors who have done this. The reason being that **the far more common reason for authors being dropped (mid-series or otherwise) is because of poor sales**, and therefore another publisher won't take a risk on the rest of the series (or the author) if it hasn't sold well. And this applies across all genres; sales are what publishers care about.

I know of many successful authors who have switched publisher but not of any who have done it mid-series.

What I see far more frequently is authors going indie and fighting to get their rights back on earlier books in the series because they cannot get a new deal and can only effectively promote a whole series (through permafree or box sets for example) if they own the rights to every book.

Indie publishing sales have taken over traditionally published sales now and **your friend may have a lot more luck going independent**. If the first books in the series didn't sell well, it may be possible to buy the rights back.

**If s/he doesn't have an agent, it may be worth approaching a few** and getting their opinions on whether it would be possible. Agents have a finger on the trad pulse and may know of publishers seeking such work.